# Please add a toolbar button or keyboard shortcut for the Keyboard style

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, editor

Not sure if this should just be here or if I should post on [Meta.Stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) - please can a mod move if you think it should be there.

When writing answers, one of the items that takes me the longest is to type the keyboard code:

```
  <kbd> </kbd>
```

I am not saying it takes hours, or is a major problem, but it is an inconvenience and 
 I think that this would make an excellent addition.

Comment: This would be handy. +1

Comment: Out of all the sites, I guess Superuser gets the most "press x, then y" type answers.

Comment: Great idea!

Comment: Reported upstream as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102841/key-equivalent-for-kbd-kbd which adds a shortcut, although a menu button would be nice too.

Comment: I was actually unaware of how to do this when I found this post. I only knew it was possible from seeing it edited into another post. I believe it would increase ease and _awareness_ with using this feature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have now created an extension that adds the requested button:

[image]

The extension is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/se-kbd-button) and should work as:

- Userscript
- Firefox Extension
- Chrome Extension
- Opera Extension

Please go to the [StackApps page](https://stackapps.com/questions/4117/kbd-button-for-editor-on-stackexchange-sites) for the latest download links and report any issues on the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/se-kbd-button/issues) and I'll look into it.

Comment: +1 - Another one where IE users are left out =(

Comment: does IE even have an extention/userscript framework?

Comment: @KevinFegan: You may want to look into IEPlus or TrixIE, but I don't have proper links for either. Also, the framework I'm using does support IE, but it's only available in the commercial version :(

Comment: Humm, I tried it with TrixIE, didn't work. This could be painful to debug. And TrixIE isn't really available any more. I can only find it on some 3rd party download portals.

Comment: Great! ... Until there is an official update or something, I am happy to mark this the answer :)

Comment: Works great on Chrome! The button icon doesn't appear for me (because `*.imgur.com` is blocked) but the button still functions fine.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I use https://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-markup-shortcuts mostly. It provides <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> as a hotkey to apply KBD markup to the selected text.

I also added this functionality to my fork of the [Super User Automatic Corrector](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/SuperUser-AutomaticCorrector/commit/3306a5138a7b990134d695a42162610cbc44c823) userscript but it's implemented poorly.

Answer (score -5):

This is used quite sparingly, so it would not be worth the time or the effort to implement this, as much as we Super Users would enjoy it.

Comment: Given that similar features already exist, how hard can it be?

Comment: Are these your words or do they come from the team? This ain't really hard, so would be nice to see the declined tag pulled out of this question.