# What kind of syntax is used to specify a button?

Tags: support, markdown

I see people use it but I do not see it listed in the [markdown help](https://meta.superuser.com/editing-help) nor in the toolbar.

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: FWIW there's a feature request asking for the keyboard button highlighter to be available on the toolbar http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1454/please-add-a-toolbar-button-or-keyboard-shortcut-for-the-keyboard-style

Comment: ...also there's a good trick to use when you want to "steal" a syntax: Just use *edit* button to see the Markdown code but don't make any changes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is probably the `<kbd>` HTML tag:

- code:

  ```
  <kbd>Compose</kbd>
  ```
- result:

  <kbd>Compose</kbd>

The outline part of the formatting is [disabled on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/23571#23571) (and MSU, is seems) due to people abusing it to draw pictures and such.

Comment: Ahhh ok. That explains your results not matching what I've seen in the past. Is it somewhere in the documentation? Perhaps I missed it. Or is this just community knowledge?

Comment: Under “Inline HTML”, the [“markdown help”](http://meta.superuser.com/editing-help) page says “Note that [we only support a very strict subset of HTML!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed)”. The last bit is a link to the MSO page that says which tags are supported, but it does not hint at the special styling applied to `<kbd>`.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Johnsen! Appreciate the clarification.