# How do I view the markdown source for a post?

Tags: support, markdown

I was trying to figure out [how users markdown a button](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1624/what-kind-of-syntax-is-used-to-specify-a-button) but I do not see a "view source" button. I could of **sworn** I've been able to see the source of a post before... somehow. Am I bugging out?

Maybe it is not available in some posts? If so, why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kinda tricky, but from the permalink of the questions [ `https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1625/how-do-i-view-the-markdown-source-for-a-post` ] replace `questions` with posts and replace the part after the number ( ie, `/how-do-i-view-the-markdown-source-for-a-post`) with `/revisions`

So the link becomes https://meta.superuser.com/posts/1625/revisions

So, in general, `http://<site>/questions/<n>/<blargh>` becomes `http://<site>/posts/<n>/revisions`

---

For answers, the concept remains the same, except you'll have to replace  in the above link with the post number for the answer, which is the number appended **after** the question.

So, this answer link is [How do I view the markdown source for a post?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1625/how-do-i-view-the-markdown-source-for-a-post/1627#1627)

To get the revisions view, the link is  https://meta.superuser.com/posts/1627/revisions

---

Once you get the revisions view just click on `View Source`.

[image]

---

AFAIR, the view source link was available only on Revisions view - which is available on a single click if the question/answer has been edited.

[image]

For others, the above link will open the revisions view and you can select the source from there.

Comment: Once a post as multiple revisions, the “revisions” link is made directly accessible as the “edited *date-goes-here*” link between the post and its comments. The OP is probably remembering seeing the “view source” links that are present for each revision on the “revisions” page. The “revisions” page is accessible even for posts with just one revision, but you have to construct the URL yourself (or via a user script or some such device). Also, the `<n>` in `posts/<n>/revisions` can be either a question number or an answer number (an answer’s post number is the latter number its permalink).

Comment: @Chris, I wasn't quite done with my posting, but yes your comment captures the gist :)

Comment: Thank you gentlemen (Mr. Johnsen for the 2nd time today)! That clears it up. Glad I'm not going bonkers :-)

Comment: You're welcome @Nimmy