# What about adding a button for <kbd> tags on the formatting bar?

Tags: feature-request, formatting

I think that it would be useful to have a button for `<kbd>` html tags in the formatting bar just above the text edit box; we still have buttons to properly format quoting and for code, but we miss this one.

I think that it will be a nice addition, would it be feasible?

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-markup-shortcuts

Comment: I'm not using greasemonkey, but thanks anyway.

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3330/the-markdown-editing-help-doesnt-include-help-for-creating-buttons).

Comment: @Sekhemty: I've now published an extension to do this. Please see the other question for the details. Cheers